# Get path of file which executed another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I would like to get the path of the file which executed another file.

`first.js`

```js
const second = require("./second.js");

exports.run = () => {

 second.run();

}
```

`second.js`

```js
exports.run = () => {

 let executedPath; // <-- ?

 console.log(`File which executed this function: ${executedPath}`);

}
```

If you throw an error in the function (`throw new Error("test")`) the console shows the following:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: test
    at exports.run (/test/two.js:5:9)
    at exports.run.<anonymous> (/test/one.js:5:8)
```

So I guess it knows which file executed `second.js` but how to get the path of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dig the value out of `new Error().stack` along these lines:

```
function executedPath(n) {
    return new Error().
        stack.
        split('\n')[n+1].
        match(/\(([^\)]*):\d+:\d+\)/)[1]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Did it like this: `new Error().stack.split("\n")[2].split("(")[1].split(":")[0]`